# Hibernate não está mapeando classes

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, java-ee, jersey

*O Hibernate que estou usando não está gerando as tabelas automaticamente*

***Meu arquivo Persistence.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="WebServiceRest" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>br.com.model.Departamento</class>

        <properties>
            <!-- Url do banco Mysql  -->
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/william" />
            <!-- Driver Conector JDBC do Mysql -->
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <!-- Usuário do banco -->
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root" />
            <!-- Senha do banco -->
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="root" />
            <!-- Mapeia todas a classes com anotações  -->
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class" />
            <!-- Debuga as querys do Sql -->
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

***Minha Classe com as anotações***

```
package br.com.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
@Table(name="departamento")
public class Departamento {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int Id;

    @Column(name="nome")
    private String Nome;

    public int getId() {
        return Id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        Id = id;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return Nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        Nome = nome;
    }



}
```

***Meu web.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>WebServiceRest</display-name>


    <servlet>

        <servlet-name>Jersey Rest</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>br.com.resources</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>

    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Rest</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


</web-app>
```

***E essas são as libs que estou usando:***

```
 antlr-2.7.7.jar
    asm-1.3.3.jar
    cdi-api-1.1-PFD.jar
    classmate-1.3.0.jar
    dom4j-1.6.1.jar
    el-api-2.2.jar
    geronimo-jta_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar
    hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.1.Final.jar
    hibernate-core-5.2.0.Final.jar
    hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar
    jackson-core-asl-1.9.2.jar
    jackson-jaxrs-1.9.2.jar
    jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.2.jar
    jackson-xc-1.9.2.jar
    jandex-2.0.0.Final.jar
    javassist-3.20.0-GA.jar
    javassist.jar
    javax.inject-1.jar
    jboss-interceptors-api_1.1_spec-1.0.0.Beta1.jar
    jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar
    jersey-apache-client-1.19.1.jar
    jersey-atom-abdera-1.19.1.jar
    jersey-client-1.19.1.jar
    jersey-core-1.19.1.jar
    jersey-guice-1.19.1.jar
    jersey-json-1.19.1.jar
    jersey-multipart-1.19.1.jar
    jersey-server-1.19.1.jar
    jersey-servlet-1.19.1.jar
    jersey-simple-server-1.19.1.jar
    jersey-spring-1.19.1.jar
    jettison-1.1.jar
    jsr250-api-1.0.jar
    jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar
    jta-1_1.jar
    lucene-core-5.5.4.jar
    lucene-queryparser-5.5.4.jar
    mysql-connector-java-5.1.45-bin.jar
    oauth-client-1.19.1.jar
    oauth-server-1.19.1.jar
    oauth-signature-1.19.1.jar
    xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar
    xml-apis-1.3.03.jar
```

*Obs não estou usando o Maven*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amigo tente alterar a seguinte propriedade

```
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
```

para

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
```

Comment: Vlw, funcionou perfeitamento, era exatamente o que estava errado.

Answer (score 1):

Cara, no seu persistence eu n estou vendo o provider...

org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider

adiciona ele e dá uma olhada melhor nesse link

https://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-java-web/uma-introducao-pratica-ao-jpa-com-hibernate/#configurando-o-jpa-com-as-propriedades-do-banco

da caelum que explica direito como implementar tua conf para o uso de JPA.

Abraço.

Comment: Sim, segui passo a passo porém ainda continuo sem o mapeamento automático.

Comment: 1. tu ja criou o banco no teu localhost?
2. como ta aparecendo no console? msg de erro ou o q? tem como disponibilizar aqui?